# How to get linebreaks into a mat-option?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a mat-selecet with four mat-options. One of these has a text, an input-field and a description in it. In the first line I want to have the text at the start and the input-field in the end. In the second line I only want to have the description.

I have already tried to display the mat-option as "contents".

```js
<mat-option class="checkbox" value="Timeout">
  <div style="width: 100%">Timeout</div>
  <div style="width: 100%; text-align: right;">
    <input type="number" matInput placeholder=""[(ngModel)]="sessionTimeout"> 
  </div>
  <div class="information">Session Timeout (seconds)</div>
</mat-option>
```

My styles:

```css
/deep/ .mat-option-text{
    display: contents !important;
}
```

My output:
https://puu.sh/DjICk/756a22bea3.png

Expected output:
https://puu.sh/DjIxu/6495d7ac7c.png